# How to compute max in one group and min another group and take the average with respect to time

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr, data-cleaning

I have a data set where there are times, prices, and a code for buy and sell. For every time period, I am trying to compute the maximum buy price and the minimum sell price then take the average. If one of them is not present at a particular time, then it will just be which ever is present. For example, if there is only a buy price, then the average is just the buy price for that time. For this data 1 is a buy and 0 is a sell. The data set looks like this:

```
data <- data.frame(buy_sell = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1)
                   ,price = c(71,65,66,77,89,80,55,45,23,46,50,45)
                   ,time = c(1,1,1,2,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,3))

data$av_price <- ifelse(data$time == 1,55.5,ifelse(data$time == 2,66,45))
data
```

I was trying to do this in dyplr but when you do group by, it computes each for both groups and so u can't take the average of two. My approach looked like this.

```
data <- data %>% group_by(time,buy_sell) %>%
                   mutate(max_buy = max(price),min_sell = min(price))
data
```

Could someone help me structure the code to give the desired result?

Comment: something like this? `data %>% group_by(time, buy_sell) %>% mutate(average_price = across(max_buy = mean(max(price)), min_sell = mean(min(price))))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with a pair of intermediate/staging columns. Something like the following:

```r
output <- data %>%
  mutate(buy_price = ifelse(buy_sell == 1, price, NA),
         sellprice = ifelse(buy_sell == 0, price, NA)) %>%
  group_by(time,buy_sell) %>%
  mutate(max_buy = max(buy_price, na.rm = TRUE),
         min_sell = min(sell_price, na.rm = TRUE))
```